# Angular UI Router Abstract template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a working application with everything working with a structure like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <!-- alot of repeated html used by all the states here -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <!-- the unique html specific to the state goes here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and router config like this

```js
$stateProvider
  .state('dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    templateUrl: './partials/dashboard.html'
  })
  .state('applications', {
    url: '/applications',
    templateUrl: './partials/applications.html'
  })
  .state('server', {
    url: '/server',
    templateUrl: './partials/server.html'
  })
```

The problem is that here is a lot of repetition of html code.
How do I make an interface that all states inherit from so that I concentrate on uniques html of a state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use abstract state, f.e. called `base`:

```
.state('base', {
  url: '',
  templateUrl: 'path/to/layout.html', // here you should declare named ui-views, f.e. named content
  abstract: true
})
.state('base.dashboard', {
  url: '/dashboard',
  views: {
    content: {
      templateUrl: "/path/to/dashboard/content.html"
    }
  }
})
// the rest of the states goes the same below.
...
```

Hope that helped somehow.

For more info please refer [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views).